# How to validate the TypeORM entities at the startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM migrations to create the database, then I have my entities and there is a mismatch between a column name in the database and one of the entities.

Even with this column mismatch I can start my application and there is no error until I send the first request to the database.

I want typeORM to compare the actual database schema with the entities in the code and throws an error if there is any mismatch, when I start the application. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I think TypeORM team is doing it. You may follow this issue https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5995 and ask